# BTRFS - How to reclaim unused space in each chunk used and compact the filesystem, basically defrag free space?

Tags: btrfs, defragmentation

How to reclaim unused space from each chunk used by BTRFS filesystem?

Let's say there are lots of chunks partially used from 10% to 50% utilised per chunk, how do I defragment those so that the 90% to 50% of free space per chunk is reclaimed?

If possible this would also compact the data.

Answer (score 0):

BTRFS has an easy way to reclaim unused space per chunk that has data in the filesystem!...  btrfs balance.

For official documentation on its usage go to the official docs and search for "**Compact under used chunks**" here: https://btrfs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/Balance.html#filter-types

The syntax is basically:

```
btrfs balance start -dusage=<percentageUsed/chunk> <btrfs mount path>
```

E.g:

```
btrfs balance start -dusage=10 /mnt/btrfs
```

The above will search all chunks in the btrfs mounted path /mnt/btrfs for any chunks that are only used up to 10%.
The data will then get relocated to other partially used chunks increasing the percentage of the chunk used to greater than 10%.
Thus compacting the filesystem and more importantly releasing unused and locked away "free-space" per chunk!

In essence, defragmenting free-space

You can then put the above in a script on ever increasing percentage up to 50%.  The official documentation in the link above does not recommend over 50% as it has less benefit.

e.g:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function free_chunks_up_to_50percent {
    local path=$1
    
    for USAGE in {10..50..10} 
    do
        echo "usage percentage= ${USAGE}"
        echo "path= ${path}"
        btrfs balance start -v -dusage=${USAGE} ${path}
    done
}

free_chunks_up_to_50percent $1
```

e.g: To execute the above script if it was a script-file called `btrfs-reclaim-unused-space.sh` for a btrfs mounted path at `/mnt/btrfs` to reclaim space there.

```
sh ./btrfs-reclaim-unused-space.sh /mnt/btrfs
```

For SSD's this is quite quick even on BTRFS RAIDs

For mechanical disks in BTRFS RAIDs this could take some time depending on the size of the RAID array (all types of BTRFS RAID).  It is still worth running it every now and then especially if you have a lot of IO happening to the RAID.  Heavy torrenting for example.

Comment: "Btrfs assistant" lets you do balancing from a GUI and/or configure it to autorun every week/month.

Comment: Looks good @HolyBlackCat I just checked it out! Alternatively if you don't have a gui you can run the above script I wrote on any frequency on crontab.

Comment: The script above will do the easy quick wins first from 10% utilisation then gradually increasing to 50% which is harder.